# How can DOM events be used with as-element?

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

In order to work around issues with browsers not liking anything but table elements in the body of a table, I'm using a custom element for `tr` like this:

```
  <tr as-element="session-row" repeat.for="session of sessions" session.bind="session"></tr>
```

However, this results in any DOM events handlers such as `mouseenter.trigger` that I put on `tr` not finding the handler that is in the custom element's view model.

So, I tried injecting the element and adding listeners in the custom element itself:

```
attached() {
    this.element.addEventListener('pointerenter', this.doPointerEnter);
    this.element.addEventListener('pointerleave', this.doPointerLeave);
}
```

In this case, the events fire just fine, and they hit the handlers. The problem with this is that it appears that at some point after `attached` runs, the view model loses the element. Even though, I take the injected element and put it in a local variable, when I want to use it later in one of the event handlers, it's `undefined`.

I have noticed that if I debug the event handler, `this` is actually the `tr` element, but my injected element variable is undefined. In the constructor when I catch the injected element `this` is the view model.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're likely getting bit by the vagaries of `this` in Javascript.

Try changing your code to:

```
attached() {
    this.element.addEventListener('pointerenter', evt => this.doPointerEnter(evt));
    this.element.addEventListener('pointerleave', evt => this.doPointerLeave(evt));
}
```

That should fix the problem for you.

Comment: Yep. That did it. The various IDE tricks and layers of transpilers hide the seedy underbelly of JavaScript sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those things that just becomes second nature after a while :-)